# How can I retrieve io.swagger.models.Swagger object in a jersey+swagger-based system?

Tags: jersey, swagger

I want to get io.swagger.models.Swagger object in my system, which is a restful backend based on jersey and swagger.

I saw in class ApiListingResource there is such a statement

```
Swagger swagger = (Swagger) context.getAttribute("swagger");
```

, which can retrieve the swagger object from servlet context.

Can I do the same in my own code?  This seems not a contract that the attribute name will always be "swagger".  So I dare not.

Is there any reliable way to retrieve the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on the context (yes, it is set to the name `swagger`, or with your own logic by extending [BeanConfig](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-generator/src/main/java/io/swagger/generator/DynamicSwaggerConfig.java)

Comment: Is there any way to make ApiListingResource.scan() get run before I retrieve the context?   If I call Swagger swagger = (Swagger) context.getAttribute("swagger") before the the url /swagger.json is visited, I will get a null object.